# Grub won't boot Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, grub-legacy

**Notice:** This is not about dual booting, I can setup GRUB to dual boot with Windows 7 later. I just need to be able to get into Arch Linux.

Last night I installed Arch onto my computer via netinstall and it all went smoothly, but when I went to reboot... it loaded up the GRUB menu and it listed Arch Linux, but when I select it, I get "Error 15: File not found."

I've been googling and trying various way to fix this problem but I always get the same error.

Some info about my partitions:

- `/dev/sda`:

  1. Windows 7 System Reserved
  2. Windows 7
- `/dev/sdb`:

  1. Data (Movies, Music, etc..)
- `/dev/sdc`:

  1. Separate Boot Partition
  2. Swap
  3. Separate Home Partition
  4. Root
- `/dev/sdd`:

  1. Pendrive

The followings are outputs of various programs and contents of various files.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Stuff" UUID="72D6355E32F06BD5" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="A8F8AC7FF8AC4CFE" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="2A20B02620AFF6CB" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="2a23abcf-b29f-4119-b406-0b1817e5c8e1" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sdc2: UUID="f3d9ce0d-5953-4f4e-885a-4cd2ebf6b6e9" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdc3: UUID="2a53bdc8-7a9a-4dd2-9aef-5b7b4c3e74a4" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc4: UUID="7b4faa93-98db-49e3-ad41-92e9dc60deda" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="PENDRIVE" UUID="0290-E580" TYPE="vfat"
```

`menu.lst`

```
timeout   5
default   0
color     light-blue/black light-cyan/blue

#===--- Arch Linux
title  Arch Linux
root   (hd2,0)
kernel /vmlinuz26 root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/2a53bdc8-7a9a-4dd2-9aef-5b7b4c3e74a4 ro vga=775
initrd /kernel26.img

#===--- Arch Linux Fallback
title  Arch Linux Fallback
root   (hd2,0)
kernel /vmlinuz26 root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/2a53bdc8-7a9a-4dd2-9aef-5b7b4c3e74a4 ro vga=775
initrd /kernel26-fallback.img

#===--- Windows 7
title         Windows 7
rootnoverify  (hd0,0)
chainloader   +1
```

`fstab`

```
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system>        <dir>         <type>    <options>          <dump> <pass>
devpts                 /dev/pts      devpts    defaults            0      0
shm                    /dev/shm      tmpfs     nodev,nosuid        0      0
/dev/sdc1              /boot         ext2      defaults            0      1
/dev/sdc2              /             ext4      defaults            0      1
/dev/sdc3              /home         ext4      defaults            0      1
/dev/sdc4              swap          swap      defaults            0      1
```

Answer (score 5):

The main thing that seems wrong here is that in the line

> kernel /vmlinuz26 root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/2a53bdc8-7a9a-4dd2-9aef-5b7b4c3e74a4 ro vga=775

You are using the **uuid** for `/dev/sdc3` which is your `/home` partition, you should be using the **uuid** for `/dev/sdc2` which is your `/` partition.

Also... the output from `sudo blkid` does not match what is shown in `fstab`. In *blkid* the swap partition is `/dev/sdc2`, but in *fstab* the swap partition is `/dev/sdc4`...

You need to figure out these descrepencies.... then you can try to re-configure your `grub.conf`

Some pointers:

- Have you tried other values of root, like `root (hd2,1)` ?
- Instead of

  > kernel /vmlinuz26 root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/2a53bdc8-7a9a-4dd2-9aef-5b7b4c3e74a4 ro vga=775`

  you could try things like

  > kernel /vmlinuz26 root=/dev/sdc2 ro vga=775
- Make sure that `/boot/kernel26.img` exists.